# Ros-win ros-catkin-tools install fail

Tags: ros-melodic, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've tried to install ros-win as described in here: https://ros-win.visualstudio.com/_git/ros-win?path=%2Fdoc%2FSetup.md&version=GBmaster
At the last step the ros-catkin-tools installation is failed, but the ros-melodic-desktop seems to install correctly.

Here's the error message:

```
ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Exception: The upgrade of ros-catkin-tools was NOT successful. Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ros-catkin-tools\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'. See log for details.
```

I checked the log, but there is no additional information regarding the problem, or I can't find it. The installation is quite straightforward so I don't know where did I miss anything.

Anyone can guess what I did wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305367/ros-win-ros-catkin-tools-install-fail/) by [CsorvaGep](https://answers.ros.org/users/37995/csorvagep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sean Yen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37768/sean-yen/) on 2018-10-10**:
Can you run `choco upgrade ros-catkin-tools` again and post the full console output? The package was just getting updated and the version of `0.0.1.1810092059` comes with some fixes for this symptom. Maybe you can give it try?

**Comment by [CsorvaGep](https://answers.ros.org/users/37995/csorvagep/) on 2018-10-10**:
I've installed on a different computer and it worked now. It is maybe because of the new version, I'll check is tomorrow.

**Comment by [Sean Yen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37768/sean-yen/) on 2018-10-10**:
Glad to hear it worked now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should:

- remove all related ROS files in Chocolatey lib folder. In windows: C:/Programdata/chocolatey/lib.
- remove the content of opt folder.
- upgrade the package in chocolatey again.

---

Originally posted by [salaheddineghamri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38514/salaheddineghamri/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0